# How to use Spoon on aws pentaho community version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

I have spinned up a Pentaho server on AWS with

```
Pragmatic Pentaho BA Server Community Edition 5.4 @ AWS Platform
```

and want to use the Kettel GUI(Spoon) to control from localhost through installed client or web browser.

How can I achieve this?

additional information:

follow the instruction in http://www.pragtech.co.in/products/other-products/pragmatic-pentaho-community-edition-aws-platform.html#launch

it is possible to get a browser client through IP

```
instance-ip:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to the BI server (`instance-ip:8080`) and DI server (`instance-ip:9080`) through browser.

But spoon is not a web application. You can connect from you local spoon to the DI Repository created in your server (`Tools --> Repository --> Connect`) and upload/ manage your ktr/kjb files there.